# Alter user-defined type column type in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have two user-defined types:

```
CREATE TYPE s.s_stavp_kv AS ENUM('k','v');
```

and

```
CREATE TYPE s.stavp_kv AS ENUM('k','v');
```

Table looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE s.zv_stavp
(
   version integer NOT NULL,
   id integer NOT NULL,
   tudu integer NOT NULL,
   kv s_stavp_kv NOT NULL,
   cobj text NOT NULL,
   iobj text NOT NULL,
   typev text
)
```

Now i need to change type of `kv` to `stavp_kv` type. Im trying something like:

```
ALTER TABLE s.zv_stavp 
  ALTER COLUMN kv TYPE stavp_kv USING ...???...;
```

But I dont know at all what to write as USING expression.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

```
ALTER TABLE s.zv_stavp 
  ALTER COLUMN kv TYPE stavp_kv USING kv::text::stavp_kv;
```